# How configure php symfony4 app inside site subfolder (routing problem)

Tags: php, routes, symfony4, subdirectory

I need to configure a symfony app inside a subfolder of a hosted domain.
The app registers some route, for example `/hello`.

The directory structure is:

```
/ (http root)
/myapp (symfony app)
/myapp/.htaccess (invisible redirect)
/myapp/public 
/myapp/src
/myapp/vendor
/myapp/...
```

With Apache mod-rewrite I redirect internally all urls from `www.mysite.test/myapp/...` to `www.mysite.test/myapp/public/...`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myapp/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then when I browse the url `www.mysite.test/myapp/hello` the app return no route for `myapp/hello`.

There is a way to mount all routes with a custom prefix to solve this problem? In this way the controllers can handle all the url with the `/myapp` prefix and also the url generated by route has this prefix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too few months ago and solved it.

[Here is my thread about this same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895202/symfony4-routing-inside-a-subfolder)

Hope It can help you.
If you have questions about my answers, fell free to ask.

Comment: Thanks, but you solution require the access to apache .conf file. My hosting provider don't allow to edit this file, I can only use .htaccess.

Comment: If I remember correctly what I did, the Apache `Alias` was necessary, so i'm not sure you'll be able to fix it without bing able to change the apache file.
You could still try to put what I have in my `/etc/apache2/sties-enabled/app.conf` in your `.htaccess` but I'm not sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I found a solution to the route not found error.

- I define a parameter `app.web_root_prefix` in `service.yaml` with the url prefix.
- I change the definition of Kernel::loadRoutes on `Kernel.php`:

```php
    class Kernel extends BaseKernel
    {
        use MicroKernelTrait {
            loadRoutes as _loadRoutes;
        }

        // [omitted code]

        public function loadRoutes(LoaderInterface $loader)
        {
            $r = $this->_loadRoutes($loader);

            $prefix = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('app.web_root_prefix');
            if (!empty($prefix)) {

            /** @var Route $route */
            foreach ($r->getIterator() as $route) {
                $path = $route->getPath();
                if (strpos($path, $prefix) !== 0 && empty(array_diff($route->getSchemes(), array('http', 'https', 'ftp')))) {
                    // Add the prefix only if it is not already there.
                    $route->setPath('/'.$prefix.$path);
                }
            }

            // $r->addPrefix($prefix);
            }
            return $r;
        }
    }
```

In this mode all routes loaded from a .yaml file are prefixed correctly.
Also you must change all paths in security.yaml inserting the prefix `%app.web_root_prefix%`.

I must make more test...