# Easier access to another web app inside Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a Symfony 4 web app. Let's assume it is http://example.com.

I have installed HESK in /public/hesk/.
Now HESK is accessible via http://example.com/hesk/index.php, but when user skips "index.php", 404 error is shown.

I have tried `return $this->redirect('...')` and `return new RedirectResponde('...')` in my controller, but browser only says that there are too many redirects.

What is the correct way to redirect /hesk and /hesk/ to /hesk/index.php?

Comment: You should configure that redirection in your .htaccess

Comment: I had this problem some months ago and I answered my own questions here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895202/symfony4-routing-inside-a-subfolder
As I said, I don't think it's the most proper way to do it, but it works. And you need to be able to edit apache sites config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Apache, you can put a `.htaccess` file in /public/hesk/ to force the redirect, something along those lines :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Or use the `DirectoryIndex index.php` directive in your virtual host directly.

For Nginx, you need to modify your vhost to add the redirect. Something like that (not tested) :

```
location /hesk {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri&$args;
}
```